# Why can't I use the same Get-Date variable twice without getting incorrect time

Tags: powershell

I want my script to write the time and date to a log when there is no internet connection.

When my `if` code is executed a log file is updated with the date and time but when the `else` code is executed that is supposed to log if the internet is down it logs the incorrect time.

```
$InternetTest = {
    Test-Connection 192.168.8.1 -Quiet
}
$WebsiteTest = {
    $result = Test-Connection 192.168.8.101 -Quiet
    $D = Get-Date

    $Outputreport0 = "Site is down!     $d"
    $Outputreport1 = "Site is Up!       $d"

    if ($result -ne 0) {
        $Outputreport1 | Out-File C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebsiteTest1\log.txt -Append
        Write-Host "Up and Running"
    } else {
        $Outputreport0 | Out-File C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebsiteTest1\log.txt -Append
        Write-Host "DOWN!!!!!!!!"
    }
}
$Timer1 = {
    function Start-Countdown {
        Param(
            [Int32]$Seconds = 10,
            [string]$Message = "Pausing for 10 seconds..."
        )
        foreach ($Count in (1..$Seconds)) {
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Retrying in $Seconds seconds, $($Seconds - $Count) left" -PercentComplete (($Count / $Seconds) * 100)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Completed" -PercentComplete 100 -Completed
    }

    Start-Countdown -Seconds 10 -Message "Local internet connection unavailable "
}
$Timer2 = {
    function Start-Countdown {
        Param(
            [Int32]$Seconds = 8,
            [string]$Message = "Pausing for 8 seconds..."
        )
        foreach ($Count in (1..$Seconds)) {
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Retrying in $Seconds seconds, $($Seconds - $Count) left" -PercentComplete (($Count / $Seconds) * 100)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Completed" -
        PercentComplete 100 -Completed
    }

    Start-Countdown -Seconds 10 -Message "Website is down"
}

$InternetReport = "Local internet is down    $d"

for () {
    Clear-Host

    if (&$InternetTest -ne 0) {
        Write-Host "Internet UP"
        &$WebsiteTest
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    } else {
        Write-Host "Internet Down"
        $InternetReport | Out-File C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebsiteTest1\Link_log.txt -Append
        &$Timer
    }
}
```

I just what the time and date to be correct in both log files.

Comment: Can you update your question with the differences in the date output?

Comment: I updated the code. The InternetReport date is always the same

Comment: Apologies should have been more clear. Can you give us an example of the string you want and the string that you are getting?

Comment: How does $websitetest get run?  It's a script block.

Comment: No problem.
[{$Outputreport0/1 | Out-File C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebsiteTest1\log.txt -Append} generates the correct tiema dn date in the log file "Site is Up!       07/31/2019 14:56:48"]
[{$InternetReport | Out-File 
    C:\Users\simeo\Desktop\WebsiteTest1\Link_log.txt -Append}
Where with this part the log is updated with the same time and date every time]

Comment: Yes its a script block

Comment: This code has several errors.  I think $internettest should be $websitetest.  The argument for out-file is on a new line.

Comment: I'm just learning about Posh so please pardon any dumb remarks

Comment: Oky i updated the code, hope you can see what i mean now

Comment: $websitetest will be blank whether it's a success or failure.  I think you need to learn the powershell fundamentals.

Comment: $websitetest runs fine no problem there is at the $internettest else code that writes the incorrect time to log file

Comment: Define "incorrect time". What timestamp do you get? What timestamp do you expect? Also, I removed the pointless comments from your code and corrected the obvious syntax errors that were probably introduced by either copy/pasting the code from a PowerShell console or a misguided attempt to fit the code into the content section. Please always create a [mcve] and copy/paste the code from *that* script into your question.

Comment: for () is an infinite loop.

Comment: $timer is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rework it this way.  Probably having a $d2 outside the script block will fix your problem.  Maybe you were accidentally setting it globally somewhere else.  I changed the log path for my own testing.

```
function InternetTest {
    Test-Connection 192.168.8.1 -Quiet -count 1 # gateway
}

function WebsiteTest {
    $result = Test-Connection microsoft.com -Quiet -count 1  # test failure, timeout 3-4 sec
    # $result = Test-Connection yahoo.com -Quiet -count 1
    $D1 = Get-Date

    $Outputreport0 = "Site is down!     $d1"
    $Outputreport1 = "Site is Up!       $d1"

    if ($result) {
        $Outputreport1 | Out-File log.txt -Append
        Write-Host "Up and Running"
    } else {
        $Outputreport0 | Out-File log.txt -Append
        Write-Host "DOWN!!!!!!!!"
    }
}

function Start-Countdown {
    Param(
        [Int32]$Seconds = 10,
        [string]$Message = "Pausing for $seconds seconds..."
    )
    foreach ($Count in 1..$Seconds) {  # watch big arrays with the .. operator
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Retrying in $Seconds seconds, $($Seconds - $Count) left" -PercentComplete ($Count / $Seconds * 100)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
    Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $Message -Status "Completed" -PercentComplete 100 -Completed
}

$d2 = get-date
$InternetReport = "Local internet is down    $d2"

for($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {  # trying it 3x
    if (InternetTest) {
        Write-Host "Internet UP"
        WebsiteTest
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    } else {
        Write-Host "Internet Down"
        $InternetReport | Out-File Link_log.txt -Append
        start-countdown # timer
    }
}
```

In fact, you can't get the $d from the script block (or function) in that way, it's a different scope:

```
& { $d = get-date }
$d  # unchanged
```

You're just starting, and you're already using anonymous functions.  Most people don't even know about them.

Comment: #js2010 
Thank you very much for the answer, it is the solution to the problem i was having i really appreciate the effort. #You the real MVP